# how to validate sigprocmask is working

Tags: linux, perl, signals

I am using sigprocmask to block signal and getting my process killed.
 It works but is there a way to validate that say using `/proc/<pid>/status`
 If I remove sigprocmask statements below the code does not work but I do not see any difference in `/proc/<pid>/status` with resepct to SigIgn,SigCgt,SigPnd ,Sig*

```
my $sigset_old = POSIX::SigSet->new;
my $sigset = POSIX::SigSet->new;
$sigset->emptyset();
$sigset->addset(&POSIX::SIGPOLL);
POSIX::sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,$sigset,$old_sigset);

while(1)
{

  POSIX::RT::Signal::sigwait($sigset);
  POSIX::sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK,$old_sigset)
 <some code>
 ...
 ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show code that explicitly demonstrates a problem?  For example, code that prints the "SigBlk:" line from `/proc/$$/status` before and after you SIG_BLOCK?  Or code that _kill()_ s itself after you SIG_BLOCK?  Correcting for imports and typos (and ignoring the rather unusual part where you unblock after a _sigwait_), your code does what I'd expect in the `status` file.  Perhaps you're not looking at the right files

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
POSIX::sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK,$old_sigset)
```

do:

```
POSIX::sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,$old_sigset)
```

The old signal mask does not contain your POLL signal, so it is not unblocked in the second call. What you want is either to set the old signal mask like shown or to unblock your signal with

```
POSIX::sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK,$sigset)
```

This is incorrectly documented in many places in the internet e.g. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/perl-cookbook/1565922433/ch16s21.html
Seems like often, one copies from the other.